# manual backup information needed in admin

Tags: database, backup

I have just done a database backup in admin but I now want to do a manual backup. Can you tell me where do I find this in admin?

To back up, find phpMyAdmin in the hosting control panel and choose “export” from the menu bar. In many cases you can stick with the “Quick” option, but, if you have more than one database in the same MySQL install, for example, choose the “Custom” option and find the relevant database in the drop-down list. Unless you know what you’re doing, leave the other options alone. Scroll to the bottom of the page, and click “Go”. A dump of the database will be downloaded and you can store it with the files you downloaded earlier or somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glamorous Hairstyles,you can do database backup from admin `goto admin>System>Tool>Backup>` here you need select backup type ad an`d click on  Database Backup` button on it create a database dump.

Comment: Can I copy this dump and store it on my computer? I have just done the backup. It now says :  gz   (The archive can be uncompressed with 7-Zip on Windows systems)  Do I just click on this and it will allow me to save it somewhere on my computer?

Comment: yes.you can download from here youmagentoinstance\var\backups folder

Comment: Hi.is it works...?

Comment: I downloaded it and now the file is saved as winRARarchive

Comment: what is problem

Comment: is this file alright when I open it , the file opens up as notepad? I am not sure what I did wrong. The file has been saved but as notepad

Comment: yes.if you extract this file you got.sql file that is proper

Comment: How often should I do this  Every week, every month....

Comment: yes.. at any times..

Comment: I am not sure if I need to do system backup and database backup in admin.... I have only done database backup..

Comment: there are option at admin>System>Tool>Backup and download from there